# Given a date, how can I efficiently calculate the next date in a given sequence (weekly, monthly, annually)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, date

In my application I have a variety of date sequences, such as Weekly, Monthly and Annually.  Given an arbitrary date in the past, I need to calculate the next *future* date in the sequence.

At the moment I'm using a sub-optimal loop.  Here's a simplified example (in Ruby/Rails):

```
def calculate_next_date(from_date)
  next_date = from_date
  while next_date < Date.today
    next_date += 1.week # (or 1.month)
  end
  next_date
end
```

Rather than perform a loop (which, although simple, is inefficient especially when given a date in the distant past) I'd like to do this with date arithmetic by calculating the number of weeks (or months, years) between the two dates, calculating the remainder and using these values to generate the next date.

Is this the right approach, or am I missing a particularly clever 'Ruby' way of solving this?   Or should I just stick with my loop for the simplicity of it all?

Comment: do you claim to be olly from ollydbg?

Answer (score 15):

Because you tagged this question as `ruby-on-rails`, I suppose you are using Rails.
ActiveSupport introduces the [calculation](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb) module which provides an helpful `#advance` method.

```
date = Date.today
date.advance(:weeks => 1)
date.advance(:days => 7)
# => next week
```

Comment: I think you mean `date.advance(:weeks => 1)`, because that code doesn't work.

Comment: `change` doesn't support the `:weeks` option. I updated the code, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I have used the [recurrence gem](http://github.com/fnando/recurrence) in the past for this purpose.  There are a few other gems that model recurring events listed [here](http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/recurring_events.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `Time` object, you can use `Time.to_a` to break the time into an array (with fields representing the hour, day, month, etc), adjust the appropriate field, and pass the array back to `Time.local` or `Time.utc` to build a new `Time` object.

If you are using the `Date` class, `date +/- n` will give you a date n days later/earlier, and `date >>/<< n` will give you a date n months later/earlier.

You can use the more generic `Date.step` instead of your loop.  For example,

```
from_date.step(Date.today, interval) {|d|
    # Each iteration of this block will be passed a value for 'd'
    #   that is 'interval' days after the previous 'd'.
}
```

where `interval` is a length of time in days.

If all you are doing is calculating elapsed time, then there is probably a better approach to this.  If your date is stored as a `Date` object, doing `date - Date.today` will give you the number of days between that date and now.  To calculate months, years, etc, you can use something like this:

```
# Parameter 'old_date' must be a Date object
def months_since(old_date)
    (Date.today.month + (12 * Date.today.year)) - (old_date.month + (12 * old_date.year))
end
def years_since(old_date)
    Date.today.year - old_date.year
end
def days_since(old_date)
    Date.today - old_date
end
```